# Taylor series for log(x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, calculus

I'm trying to evaluate a Taylor polynomial for the natural logarithm, ln(x), centred at a=1 in Python. I'm using the series given on Wikipedia however when I try a simple calculation like ln(2.7) instead of giving me something close to 1 it gives me a gigantic number. Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

```
def log(x):
    n=1000
    s=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        s += ((-1)**(i+1))*((x-1)**i)/i
    return s
```

Using the Taylor series:

[image]

Gives the result:
[image]

EDIT: If anyone stumbles across this an alternative way to evaluate the natural logarithm of some real number is to use numerical integration (e.g. Riemann sum, midpoint rule, trapezoid rule, Simpson's rule etc) to evaluate the integral that is often used to define the natural logarithm;

[image]

Comment: Instead of image, can you post it as a text

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That series is only valid when x is <= 1.  For x>1 you will need a different series.

For example this one  (found [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/lnseries.html)):

```
def ln(x): return 2*sum(((x-1)/(x+1))**i/i for i in range(1,100,2))
```

output:

```
ln(2.7)        # 0.9932517730102833

math.log(2.7)  # 0.9932517730102834
```

*Note that it takes a lot more than 100 terms to converge as x gets bigger (up to a point where it'll become impractical)*

You can compensate for that by adding the logarithms of smaller factors of x:

```
def ln(x):
    if x > 2: return ln(x/2) + ln(2)  # ln(x) = ln(x/2 * 2) = ln(x/2) + ln(2)
    return 2*sum(((x-1)/(x+1))**i/i for i in range(1,1000,2))
```

which is something you can also do in your Taylor based function to support x>1:

```
def log(x):
    if x > 1: return log(x/2) - log(0.5) # ln(2) = -ln(1/2)
    n=1000
    s=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        s += ((-1)**(i+1))*((x-1)**i)/i
    return s
```

These series also take more terms to converge when x gets closer to zero so you may want to work them in the other direction as well to keep the actual value to compute between 0.5 and 1:

```
def log(x):
    if x > 1:   return log(x/2) - log(0.5) # ln(x/2 * 2) = ln(x/2) + ln(2)
    if x < 0.5: return log(2*x) + log(0.5) # ln(x*2 / 2) = ln(x*2) - ln(2) 
    ...
```

*If performance is an issue, you'll want to store ln(2) or log(0.5) somewhere and reuse it instead of computing it on every call*

for example:

```
ln2 = None
def ln(x):
    if x <= 2:
        return 2*sum(((x-1)/(x+1))**i/i for i in range(1,10000,2))
    global ln2
    if ln2 is None: ln2 = ln(2)    
    n2 = 0
    while x>2: x,n2 = x/2,n2+1
    return ln2*n2 + ln(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

The program is correct, but the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) has the following caveat:

> The series converges to the natural logarithm (shifted by 1) whenever −1 < x ≤ 1.

The series diverges when `x > 1`, so you shouldn't expect a result close to 1.

Comment: Is there an alternative series I can use if I want to compute the natural logarithm for any real x?

Comment: The farther away from ln(1), the slower the convergence. For some good high-precision formulae, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Numerical_value.

Comment: @tail_recursion Maybe to make use of the series you have, you can reduce the argument x to something less than 1 by looking at log(x / a) = log(x) + log(a) where a is a power of e. I.e. find the "decade" in which x falls (perhaps by repeated powers of e until you find one bigger than x) and then work with x/exp(m) where m is the number of powers you tried, and then add m to the result.

Answer (score -1):

The python function [`math.frexp(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.frexp) can be used to advantage here to modify the problem so that the taylor series is working with a value close to one. `math.frexp(x)` is described as:

> Return the mantissa and exponent of x as the pair (m, e). m is a float
> and e is an integer such that x == m * 2**e exactly. If x is zero,
> returns (0.0, 0), otherwise 0.5 <= abs(m) < 1. This is used to “pick
> apart” the internal representation of a float in a portable way.

Using `math.frexp(x)` should not be regarded as "cheating" because it is presumably implemented just by accessing the bit fields in the underlying binary floating point representation. It isn't absolutely guaranteed that the representation of floats will be IEEE 754 binary64, but as far as I know every platform uses this. [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) can be examined to find out the actual representation details.

Much [like the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66490422/238704) does you can use the standard logarithmic identities as follows: Let `m, e = math.frexp(x)`. Then log(x) = log(m * 2<sup>e</sup>) = log(m) + e * log(2). log(2) can be precomputed to full precision ahead of time and is just a constant in the program. Here is some code illustrating this to compute the two similar taylor series approximations to log(x). The number of terms in each series was determined by trial and error rather than rigorous analysis.

taylor1 implements log(1 + x) = x<sup>1</sup> - (1/2) * x<sup>2</sup> + (1/3) * x<sup>3</sup> ...

taylor2 implements log(x) = 2 * [t + (1/3) * t<sup>3</sup> + (1/5) * t<sup>5</sup> ...], where t = (x - 1) / (x + 1).

```py
import math
import struct

_LOG_OF_2 = 0.69314718055994530941723212145817656807550013436025

def taylor1(x):
    m, e = math.frexp(x)
    log_of_m = 0
    num_terms = 36
    sign = 1
    m_minus1_power = m - 1
    for k in range(1, num_terms + 1):
        log_of_m += sign * m_minus1_power / k
        sign = -sign
        m_minus1_power *= m - 1
    return log_of_m + e * _LOG_OF_2


def taylor2(x):
    m, e = math.frexp(x)
    num_terms = 12
    half_log_of_m = 0
    t = (m - 1) / (m + 1)
    t_squared = t * t
    t_power = t
    denominator = 1
    for k in range(num_terms):
        half_log_of_m += t_power / denominator
        denominator += 2
        t_power *= t_squared
    return 2 * half_log_of_m + e * _LOG_OF_2
```

This seems to work well over most of the domain of log(x), but as x approaches 1 (and log(x) approaches 0) the transformation provided by x = m * 2<sup>e</sup> actually produces a less accurate result. So a better algorithm would first check if x is close to 1, say abs(x-1) < .5, and if so the just compute the taylor series approximation directly on x.

Answer (score -2):

My answer is just using the Taylor series for In(x). I really hope this helps. It is simple and straight to the point.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjH1E.png)

Comment: Images of code are an unhelpful way to present code. Just paste it as text

Comment: The use of image to share code is outlawed, please use `code sample` or `code snippet`, it would make your answer more clear and understandable